# pandas data transformation long-wide-long

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

how to get data from this form (long representation of data):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c0': ['A','A','B'],
    'c1': ['b','c','d'],
    'c2': [1, 3,4]})

print(df)
```

Out:

```
   c0 c1  c2
0  A  b   1
2  A  c   3
3  B  d   4
```

to this form :

```
   c0 c1  c2
0  A  b   1
2  A  c   3
3  A  d   NaN
4  B  b   NaN
5  B  c   NaN
6  B  d   4
```

Is long to wide to long transformation the only approach to doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***method 1***
`unstack` and `stack`

```
df.set_index(['c0', 'c1']).unstack().stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
```

[image]

***method 2***
`reindex` with product

```
df.set_index(['c0', 'c1']).reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.c0.unique(), df.c1.unique()], names=['c0', 'c1'])
).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: set_index will do cartesian product of c0, c1?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi no!  `unstack` will.

Comment: @piRSquared  thanks, I was going to update my question to add multiple value columns, which seemed to be a problem when using ``pandas.melt``, but your method addresses that well